# How to (Memory Limited) > grep -F -f file_A file_B >> output.txt

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, grep, scripting

file_A (~500MB, 1.6M lines) consists of all equal length search terms, 1 per line, not sorted.

file_B consists of all equal length text lines, 1 per line, not sorted

I've been able to run "grep -F -f file_A file_B >> output.txt" with any size file_B without problem on a box with 52GB ram. Problem is I'm now limited to 4GB ram and thus the size of file_A is now too large for this to run without exhausting available memory.

Short of manually chopping up file_A into smaller bites, is there any easy way to script this to grep for first 1000 lines of file_A, then when thats finished to automatically grep for lines 1001-2000, ect. until I've gone through all of file_A?

Comment: Use `split` to chop up the pattern file, that would be easiest.

Comment: Does the answer below solve your problem? If so, please use the checkmark to indicate so. Otherwise, let us know what's missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Loop through chunks of file_A, sending them as stdin to the same grep statement; adjust 1000 to your available memory:

```
nlines=$(wc -l < file_A)
chunk=1000
for((i=1; i < nlines; i += chunk)) 
do 
  sed -n $i,+$((chunk - 1))p file_A | grep -F -f - file_B
done > output
```

Comment: Correction, should be: `sed -n $i,+$((chunk - 1))p file_A`. Because, else we will have next ranges in the `sed`: `sed 1, 1001; sed 1001, 2001; sed 2001, 3001;` See? Last line of the previous range the same as first line of the next range. Repeating occur. Wanted to solve this the same way, but didn't know how to pass output to the `grep -f`.

Comment: excellent catch; thank you! I've updated the code accordingly

Comment: Thanks for this code. This worked flawlessly for several months. I actually split the File_A into several segments and ran the above code on each segment using Parallel. I tweaked the chunk size to maximize how many instances I could run while keeping memory out of swap and it sped things up substantially.

Comment: However, something has changed (either the way the system interprets this, or more likely I've hosed something up that is negatively impacting things)

#!/bin/bash

nlines=$(wc -l < Xab)
chunk=100000
for((i=1; i < nlines; i += chunk)) 
do 
  echo "Xab started: $(date), line = ${i}"
  sed -n $i,+$((chunk - 1))p Xab | grep -F -f - *.* >> Match.lst
done

this will print the entire test file to Match.lst if there is a hit at grep. Not sure what the problem is