# Removing lines in LARGE text file containing string found in other LARGE text file - FILES SORTED

Tags: text-processing, grep, comm

Still having issues trying to remove lines in a LARGE file containing strings listed in another LARGE file.

```
  grep -vwFf file1 file2 - FAILS due to memory exhaustion.
```

I have used:

```
  comm -23 file1 file2
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file][1]

It works for sorted files and really large files - but it only works for removing duplicate lines - not removing lines containing a string.

The two large files I have are sorted so that the strings I am searching for are at the begining of every line:

text file:

```
  AAAAA blah blah blah
  AAAAB blas blas blas
  CCCCC sdf sf sdf
```

string file

```
  AAAAA
  CCCCC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe will be wise to add those files in database and run some select (and subselect)

Comment: does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375294/how-to-memory-limited-grep-f-f-file-a-file-b-output-txt/375347#375347 help?

Comment: Similar question: [Fastest way to find lines of a file from another larger file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-file-from-another-larger-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not burst `$file1` into many smaller ones (in /tmp or use mktemp), then loop over each `$file1`, using it for grep ... what the ideal size of the pattern file (`$file1`) is, depends on your system.

Here, each `$file1` will have 1000 lines.

`i=1
while [ $i -lt $count ] 
do sed -n "$i,$(($i +1000))p" file1.txt >> /tmp/file${1}.txt 
i=$(( $i + 1001)) 
done`

Now you have a bunch of files in /tmp named file.txt, so you do:

`for file1 in $(ls /tmp/file*.txt)
do
grep -vwFf $file1 file2
done`

Safer with mktemp:

`TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp)`

`for file1 in $(ls ${TEMP_DIR}/file*.txt)
do
grep -vwFf $file1 file2
done`