# grep -v -f alternative

Tags: linux, grep

I have two files. I want to exclude anything that is in file 2 from file 1.

Example)

File #1 - List of 500 domain names

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
etc..
```

File #2 - Alexa's Top 1,000,000 domain names

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
etc..
```

I would think this would work.

```
cat file1 | grep -v -f file2 > results
```

This always results in "Killed" for anything over 10k+ in file2.

`/var/log/messages` shows it runs out of memory. The box has 12GB RAM.

```
Aug 25 02:21:18 V-RHEL-EM kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 13779 (grep) score 860 or sacrifice child
Aug 25 02:21:18 V-RHEL-EM kernel: Killed process 13779 (grep), UID 0, total-vm:9377064kB, anon-rss:7400368kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `cat` command is useless, directly use `grep ..... file1`.

Comment: Also, you should be using `-F` because the domain names in file2 are all fixed strings, not regular expressions.

Comment: and see also [Removing lines in LARGE text file containing string found in other LARGE text file - FILES SORTED](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/376036/7696)

Comment: For me it works fine with 4 GB RAM and option `-F` as @cas suggested.

Comment: if order of output doesn't matter, how about this? `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} ($0 in a){delete a[$0]} END{for(k in a) print k}' file1 file2` note that file1 is used first to create an array and any match in file2 will keep removing it from the array and then finally all keys of array is printed

Comment: you can also use `comm -23 file1_sorted file2_sorted` where you use `sort` to first create sorted versions and then use `comm`, but I think the `awk` one can easily handle larger file2 as it depends on file1 size, not file2

Comment: I voted to reopen. This is not an exact dupe as the linked solution does not address the _exclusion_ (`-v`) of lines. Also, it does not `grep` for whole lines (`-x`). Imagine `domain1.com` in file1 and `domain1.co` in file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with fixed strings, add the `-F` flag and to match whole lines, add the `-x` flag.
You don't need `cat` here, `grep` can be used with a file argument.

```
grep -F -x -v -f file2 file1 > results
```

---

You could split `file2` into `N` parts, run `grep` on each part and use the result as input file for the next run:

```
# split file2 into N=4 parts file2.00 file2.01 file2.02 file2.03
split -nl/4 -d file2 file2.

# use results as input file
cp file1 results

for f2 in file2.??; do
        grep -F -x -v -f "$f2" results > rtemp && mv rtemp results
done

# cleanup
rm file2.??
```

Adjust `N=4` as needed.